# Mongoose cannot findById in async.map function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, mongoose

The following code works fine:

```
Field.findById(fieldIdArray[0], function(err, field){
  console.log(field);
  return next();
});
```

The following code gives the erroruncaught TypeError: Invalid select() argument

```
async.map(fieldIdArray, function (fieldId, callback) {
  console.log(fieldId);
  Field.findById(fieldId, function (err, field){
    if(err) callback(err);
    if(!field) callback('Field not found.');
    field.remove(function (err){
      if(err) callback(err);
      callback(null, fieldId);
    });
  }, function (err, results){
    if(err) next(new Error('Something went wrong with deleting fields.'));
    return next();
  });
});
```

the console.log console logs out the correct fieldId, however why is an error thrown at Field.findById?

Comment: Full error: Uncaught TypeError: Invalid select() argument. Must be string or object.

And I tried to .toString() it produces the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing 3 arguments to `Field.findById`: `fieldId` (presumably an id) and 2 functions.  The first function is interpreted as the optional `fields` argument, but as the error says that argument must be a string or object.  You probably meant to pass the extra function as the third argument to `async.map`, since that expects 3 arguments and you're only passing 2.

Comment: Ah jeez don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks!